# i= Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine()) [Deprecated].. How to resolve it?

Tags: java, deprecated

I have encountered the following error while compiling my Demo code on DataInputStreamDemo:
error:

```
i= Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine()) [Deprecated]
```

//where dis = reference  DataInputStream obj

Comment: language? version? what type is "dis"? Link to the deprecated method in online documentation so we can suggest an alternative, if you don't already work it out from reading the notes in the docs?

Comment: java se 1.6, data type : DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(resource)

Comment: readLine() in java.io.DataInputStream has been deprecated

Comment: Awesome, can you provide a link to the docs where it says this? It should also state what you should use instead.

Comment: thanx fa the reply.. It's just warning... My code compiled fine... Thanx anyways StackOverFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason** for the method being deprecated :

> This method does not properly convert bytes to characters.

**Solution**

Existing code : `DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);`

Modified code : `BufferedReader d
          = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));`

[refrences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged given as how links can die over time. Links are great, but your answer should be able to hold up on its own.

Comment: sure sir , I will keep this in mind for my future posts. :)
since the same content is answered i'll leave this post as it is to avoid duplication of answer

Comment: These comments will help me write better answers in future :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc for this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) makes it reasonably clear why it's deprecated, and has been for a long time, and suggests a better alternative.

Quoting from the Javadoc:

This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the BufferedReader.readLine() method. Programs that use the DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:

```
 DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
```

with:

```
 BufferedReader d
      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```